# PHP session lifetime

Tags: php, session

Most of my website's pages are open to everyone, but a few protected pages require logging in. The login always passes through the same starting page. After logging in the user should be able to move freely between the protected pages until she exits them, either by going to one of the free pages or by going to another site altogether. When she does leave the protected pages she has to log in again to enter them again.
How can I achieve this?

**edit**
I'm thinking along the lines of checking which page the user is coming from, and if it's outside the protected range lead her to the login again.
*end of edit*

At the moment there's just one protected page, and I unset the session's username when I open that page, but that already requires logging in again when I just refresh the page. So that's not how I want it.

Comment: Please, if you downvote, leave a comment why you think it's a bad question. That allows me to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can invalidate a session, if it exists, on each non-protected page.

But: Think about the user experience. If a user opens a non-protected page in a different tab and wants to move in the protected space afterwards, he has to login again.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid. I don't know where/when I should invalidate the session. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Is the requirement to re-login from you or your customer? If it is from the customer, discuss the implications with him. If it is from you... well you could make a hybrid solution by recording the last time a user has logged-in in the session and invalidate it from a non-protected page only if it is older than x minutes, or after accessing y number of non-protected pages.

Comment: The requirement is mine. I already found a question about the timeout here, but that's a fallback solution. Also I'd rather use a timeout that a number of page access limit. Still I wonder if there's a solution to my original problem. I update my question.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you state the reason why you came up with the requirement. You can use a combination of referrer check (where does the user come from), time (how long ago was the last login) and counting of access to unprotected pages of course.